# Difficulty in Proving Symbolic Equality in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, symbolic, expression-manipulation

I'm currently working with the Mathematica software to verify the symbolic equality between two mathematical expressions. However, I've encountered a challenge where Mathematica's symbolic manipulation routines do not seem to recognize the equality between the expressions, even though I'm confident that they are mathematically equivalent.

The expressions involved are:

```
f(x) = x^2
g(x) = e^x
comp = g[f[x]]
h(x) = e^{x^2}
```

I've attempted various approaches, including using `Simplify`,`PossibleZeroQ`, and direct symbolic comparison with `===`, to evaluate if `comp` equals `h`. For example, `PossibleZeroQ[comp - h]`. However, all of these methods have returned "`False`" for the equality check.

**My Question:**

Are there alternative techniques or strategies I can use in Mathematica to prove the symbolic equality between these expressions?
Is there a specific reason why Mathematica might be having trouble recognizing this equality?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there alternative techniques or strategies I can use in
> Mathematica to prove the symbolic equality between these expressions?

If you use correct syntax, it should work

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[x_]:=x^2;
g[x_]:=Exp[x];
comp=g[f[x]];
h[x_]:=Exp[x^2];
```

And now

```
comp==h[x]
(*True*)
```

And

```
comp - h[x]
(* 0 *)
```